# mongodb findoneandupdate not returning response nor error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mean.io, database

Am trying to request the DB for an Item that has the filter:

```
{
    paid : true,
    'budget.credits': {$gt : 0},
    retrieveView : { $ne : userId }
}
```

and to update that item to include the user's Id, sort of like a "view" function so that he will not see the same item again:

```
{       
    $inc : { "retrieveCount" : 1 } ,
    $addToSet: { retrieveView: userId } 
}
```

This is the example of the server side function which receives a http.Get call

```
export function findOnePaidItem(req, res) {
    var userId = req.params.userId;

    return Item.findOneAndUpdate({
        paid : true,
        'budget.credits': {$gt : 0},
        retrieveView : { $ne : userId }
    },{         
        $inc : { "retrieveCount" : 1 } ,
        $addToSet: { retrieveView: userId } 
    },{
        maxTimeMS  : 1000
    })
        .then(responseWithResult(res))
        .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

This method works fine when there is a result to return, however when there is no longer and Item that fits the filter, the query never returns anything and continues loading as though waiting for the response.

I tried using the maxTimeMS option, hoping to get a return if past a certain time, but to no avail.

Have been bumped out with this for a long time now, any gurus out there who know this specific issue in MongoDB..?

## Update #1 **Jain's advice**

```
export function findOnePaidItem(req, res) {
    var userId = req.params.userId;

    return Item.findOneAndUpdate({
        paid : true,
        'budget.credits': {$gt : 0},
        retrieveView : { $ne : userId }
    },{         
        $inc : { "retrieveCount" : 1 },
        $addToSet: { retrieveView: userId } 
    },{
        maxTimeMS  : 100
    }).exec(function(err, res) {
        console.log(err); // null
        console.log(res); // null
        return res;
    })
        .then(responseWithResult(res))
        .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

Both variable returns null in the exec comment, am utterly confused >.< haha

## Update #2 **Stuart's & Johnny's advice**

```
export function findOnePaidItem(req, res) {
    var userId = req.params.userId;

    return Item.findOneAndUpdate({
        paid : true,
        'budget.credits': {$gt : 0},
        retrieveView : { $ne : userId }
    },{         
        $inc : { "retrieveCount" : 1 },
        $addToSet: { retrieveView: userId } 
    },{
        maxTimeMS  : 100
    }).exec(function(err, result) {
        console.log(err); // null
        console.log(result); // returns Item from DB *Thank you Stuart Bourhill

        if(!result) {
            res.status(401).send("empty file");
        } else {
             res.status(200).json(result);
        }
        return;
    });
}
```

Thank you **Stuart Bourhill** for the valuable advice given, certainly when coding, I tend to overlook on duplicate parameter names, especially so with Angular JS modular references. In my case of **update #1**, I had duplicated the *res* parameter.

## Why do I have so many issues >.<"

After successfully fixing the API call with help of Jain's, Stuart's & Johnny's advice, I experienced an error when called with Angular's *$http.get* function.

[image: server side error]

This error seems to happen when the result is empty, when there is a result present, the return call successfully ends.

snippet of the execution code (client side):

```
Auth.getCurrentUser(function(user) {                

    console.log(user._id);
    if(user._id) {

        console.log("sending");
        return $http.get('/api/items/paid/' + user._id).then(function(data) {

            paidItemPageDetails = data; 
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return err;
        });     
    } else {
        return {data:null};
    }       
});
```

Thank you guys so much for getting me so far, I am super satisfied and <3 to Stackoverflow gurus :)

## Fix to 'hardStop' Fatal Error

https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/1556

The trick is to not console.log an object, rather, to console.log a string object, which can be written as console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

Cheers and let me know if this helps you too~

Comment: Have you tried using a callback instead of a promise? mpromise which is the default promise library used by mongoose is depreciated so you could try and plug in your own promise library. Also remember that findOneAndUpdate() does not return a fully fledged promise which (although it does have a **.then**) method.

Comment: i think you need to use exec in place of then in mongoose
.exec(function(err, res){});

Comment: @StuartBourhill Am using bluebird to promisify the Item model, wonder if it has affects in some way

Comment: What you're showing in Update #1 is expected behavior as a document to update wasn't found, so `res` is null. This isn't an error, so `err` is also null. You wouldn't expect a SQL query that finds no rows to throw an error, would you? :)

Comment: So in your code that uses promises, I would expect `responseWithResult` to be called with a value of `null`. Is that what's happening?

Comment: It wouldn't throw an error. It's likely that `responseWithResult(res)` isnt handling the case for no results. You'd have to do something like `if(!result) res.status(404).send("not found"); return;` Also, and this is just a heads up, beware of using the variable name **res** you can easily overwrite the response object (also named res) if youre not careful. Happened to me once or twice and it can cause major debugging headaches!